# A question on Lorentzian matrices from “Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds” by John G. Ratcliffe

Tags: manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry

I’m stuck understanding the implication from questions 3 and 4 in Exercise 3.1 of the book Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds, hoping someone can help! I have provided some details at the bottom explaining terminology used here and in the book.

Q3. Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be a matrix in $O(1, n − 1)$. Show that A is positive (negative) if and only if $a_{11} > 0$ ($a_{11} < 0$).

Q4. Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be a matrix in $O^{+}(1, n − 1)$. Prove that $a_{11} ≥ 1$ with equality if and only if A is orthogonal.

By Q3, a matrix $A$ in $O(1, n − 1)$ with $a_{11}=1/2$ is positive. I.e. it’s in $O^{+}(1, n − 1)$. But by Q4, such a matrix must have $a_{11} \geq 1$. A contradiction. I must be missing something, hoping someone can advise.

Some more detail on notation and terminology from the book:

- $O(1, n − 1)$ is the set of Lorentzian $n x n$ matrices.
- A Lorentzian matrix A is said to be positive (resp. negative) if and only if A transforms positive time-like vectors into positive (resp. negative) time-like vectors.
- $O^{+}(1, n − 1)$ is the set of all positive matrices in $O(1, n − 1)$.

[image]

Comment: Hint: look at the vector $Ae_{1}$.

Comment: Thank you @MoisheKohan! This is super helpful regarding solving the exercise questions. However, the apparent contradiction I have observed still remains a point of confusion for me. The only explanation I have is I am wrong to think that the set of positive matrices in $0(1, n-1)$ is the same thing as $0^{+}(1, n-1)$. Any more ideas?

Comment: Yes, this is wrong

Comment: Thank you again @MoisheKohan. I wonder if you could explain why I am wrong to say $O^{+}(1, n − 1)$ is the set of all positive matrices in $O(1, n − 1)$. You can see I’ve added a screenshot from the book, where you can see around the middle of the page this is stated. There must be some subtlety that I’m overlooking. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment: The statement that $O^+(1,n-1)$ is the set of all positive matrices in $O(1,n-1)$ is tautologically correct (it is simply the definition of $O^+(1,n-1)$).

Comment: Thanks again @MoisheKohan. In that case my observation of an apparent contradiction remains unresolved. Any further thoughts?

Comment: Which contradiction? I do not see any.

Comment: By Q3, a matrix $A$ in $O(1, n − 1)$ with $a_{11}=1/2$ is positive. I.e. it’s in $O^{+}(1, n − 1)$. But by Q4, such a matrix must have $a_{11} \geq 1$. A contradiction.

Comment: I will write a proper answer later on. But one thing to note is that $a_{11}=1/2$ is impossible for $A\in O(1,n-1)$.

Comment: That’s really interesting @MoisheKohan. Curiously that would seem to show the result illustrated by Q3 is incorrect. Is it possible there is an error in the question?

Comment: No, it is all correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q(x)=x_1^2-x_2^2-... -x_n^2$ be the quadratic form invariant under the group $G=O(1,n-1)$. The hyperboloid
$H=\{x: q(x)=1\}$ is  $G$-invariant and has two components: One (let's call it $H_+$) is contained in the half-space $\{x: x_1>0\}$ and the other (let's call it $H_-$) is contained in the half-space $\{x: x_1< 0\}$. The key observation (which is an elementary exercise in algebra) is that the intersection of $H$ with the open slab
$$
\{x: -1< x_1<1\}
$$
is empty and the intersection of $H$ with the boundary of the slab consists of just two points: $\pm e_1$. In particular,

The next observation is that the first component of the vector $Ae_1$ is $a_{11}$. In particular, $a_{11}$ cannot belong to the interval $(-1,1)$.

Thus, $Ae_1\in H_+$ if and only if $a_{11}\ge 1$, equivalently, $a_{11}>0$. Similarly, $Ae_1\in H_-$ if and only if $a_{11}\le -1$, equivalently, $a_{11}<0$.

Since $H_\pm$ are connected, it follows that $A\in O^{+}(1,n-1)$ if and only if for each "positive" vector $x$ (i.e. a vector satisfying $q(x)>0$ if and only if
$Ae_1\in H_+$, if and only if $a_{11}\ge 1$. Similarly, for negative matrices $A$ in $O(1,n-1)$.

This answers affirmatively your question Q3.

To answer Q4 you should think about the vector $Ae_1$ assuming that $a_{11}=1$. Then use the fact that $A$ preserves the quadratic form $q$ to verify orthogonality of $A$. To check the converse, assume that $A\in O(n)\cap O^+(1,n-1)$ and note that it preserves both the unit sphere (with respect to the Euclidean metric) and the upper hyperboloid $H_+$. Then compute $Ae_1$.

All in all, there are no contradictions in the statements of the textbook you are reading.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you. The crucial point, for me, is that $a_{11}$ cannot be less than 1. In my view Q3, although being correct, is somewhat unnecessarily misleading in that regard. Especially when immediately followed by Q4. Just my personal opinion. Many thanks again for your time and help on this.